# go buildの-buildmode=archiveの使い方

Tags: go

go buildのbuildmodeにarchiveというものがありますが、これはなぜ存在しているのでしょうか?

初めはCなどでのArchiveファイル(.a file)のようにソースコードがなくてもリンクできるライブラリを出力するためのものかと思ったのですが、
Goのdocumentを見てみると

> In Go 1.12 and earlier, it was possible to distribute packages in binary form without including the source code used for compiling the package.

[build - The Go Programming Language](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Binary_Only_Packages)

となっており最新のGoのバージョンではこのようなビルド方法を使うことはできないようです。

この`-buildmode=archive`はどのようなときに使うのでしょうか?
(Goのcompilerが使う用途かもしれませんが)